# Ошибка компиляции при использовании аргумента sqrt

Tags: c, функции, компиляция

При компиляции программы, выдаётся ошибка `error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘sqrt’`. Ошибка повторяется в строках 19 и 23.

```
#include<stdio.h>       //
#include<math.h>        //
#include<conio.h>       //
void main () {      //о
    float x, a, y;      // 

    clrscr();       //

    FILE *f1;       //

    f1=fopen("5.txt","w");      //
    puts("Vvedit x:");      //
    scanf("%f", &x);        //

    puts("Vvedit a:");      //
    scanf("%f", &a);        //

    if(x<0.7){      //
        y=sqrt(cos)*(x+a)-(7*(x+a));        //
        fprintf(f1, "y=%f\t x=%f\t a=%f\n",y,x,a);      //
    }
    else{
        y=(sqrt((sin),3)*(x+a)-pow((cos), 2)*(x+a));        // 
        fprintf(f1, "y=%f\t x=%f\t a=%f\n",y,x,a);      //
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не заставляйте нас считать строки. Отметьте их в комментариях, например `// <-- ошибка в 19 строке`

Comment: Так у функции квадратного корня только один аргумент. Что тут имелось в виду `(sqrt((sin),3)` ???

Comment: @MBo, sin^3*(x+a)

Comment: синус приеимает аргумент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обязательно почитайте о правилах записи выражений

В ветке else должны использоваться выражения

```
pow(sin(x+a), 3) 
и
pow(cos(x+a), 2)
```

а про `sqrt(cos)*(x+a)-(7*(x+a));`  ещё нужно уточнить